# SUM IF across 2 tables not reflecting correct numbers

Tags: mysql

Here's the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE purchases_2018_1 (
  name varchar(20), 
  units SMALLINT, 
  ts int
);
INSERT INTO purchases_2018_1 (name, units, ts) 
  VALUES
    ('John', 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-03 12:00:00')),
    ('John', 2, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-04 12:00:00')),
    ('John', 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01 12:00:00')),
    ('John', 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01 12:00:00')), # histSum = 20 instead of 5
    ('Jill', 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01 12:00:00')),
    ('Jill', 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01 12:00:00')),
    ('Jill', 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-20 12:00:00')),
    ('Jill', 2, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-13 12:00:00')), # histSum = 20 instead of 5            
    ('Jack', 10, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-08 12:00:00')), # histSum = 10 (correct)
    ('Jean', 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-11 12:00:00')); # histSum = 1 (correct)

CREATE TABLE purchases_2018_2 (name varchar(20), units SMALLINT, ts int);
INSERT INTO purchases_2018_2 (name, units, ts) 
  VALUES
    ('John', 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-01 00:00:00')),
    ('John', 4, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-01 00:00:00')),
    ('John', 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-07 10:00:00')),
    ('John', 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-07 10:00:00')), # currSum = 8 instead of 2
    ('Jill', 7, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-07 10:00:00')),
    ('Jill', 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-07 10:00:00')), # currSum = 32 instead of 8
    ('Jill', 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-01 00:00:00')),
    ('Jill', 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-01 00:00:00')),            
    ('Jack', 7, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-07 10:00:00')), # currSum = 7 (correct)
    ('Jean', 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-01 00:00:00')); # currSum = 0 (correct)
```

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
    jan.name,
    SUM(IF(jan.ts BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01 00:00:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-01 00:00:00'), jan.units, 0)) AS histSum,
    SUM(IF(feb.ts BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-07 07:00:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-07 12:00:00'), feb.units, 0)) AS currSum
FROM purchases_2018_1 AS jan 
JOIN purchases_2018_2 AS feb 
ON jan.name = feb.name
GROUP BY jan.name;
```

Here's the result:

```
name    histSum currSum
Jack    10      7
Jean    1       0
Jill    20      32
John    20      8
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6k63fwxeUFfMEyF7foHtYh/32).
I'm definitely doing something wrong. Could anyone lend a hand? I must have missed out on some important facts in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the rows of both tables using UNION  instead of joining them,

```
SELECT  Name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN MTH = 'Jan' THEN TotalUnit ELSE 0 END) histSum, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN MTH = 'Feb' THEN TotalUnit ELSE 0 END) currSum
FROM
        (
            SELECT  name, 
                    SUM(units) TotalUnit,
                    'Jan' AS MTH
            FROM    purchases_2018_1
            WHERE   ts BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01 00:00:00') 
                    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-01 00:00:00')
            GROUP   BY name
            UNION   ALL
            SELECT  name, 
                    SUM(units) TotalUnit,
                    'Feb' AS MTH
            FROM    purchases_2018_2
            WHERE   ts BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-07 07:00:00') 
                    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-07 12:00:00')
            GROUP   BY name
        ) subquery
GROUP   BY Name
```

Here's a [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76dc02e/1)

Comment: Thanks @John Woo... but wouldn't this query be really inefficient if it had to load 2 entire tables into memory? (I'm not sure if the engine actually does that.) There must be a better way... a way where we can just go through these tables in a singular pass through the tables...

Comment: in the first place, why would you store different tables for each month? why not just store them in one table since you already have dates that can you can filter.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method:

```
SELECT  JanResult.Name,
        JanResult.histSum, 
        FebResult.currSum 
FROM
        (
            SELECT
                jan.name As Name,
                SUM(IF(jan.ts BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01 00:00:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-01 00:00:00'), jan.units, 0)) AS histSum
            FROM purchases_2018_1 AS jan 
            GROUP BY jan.name
        ) as JanResult
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                feb.name As Name,
                SUM(IF(feb.ts BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-07 07:00:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-07 12:00:00'), feb.units, 0)) AS currSum
            FROM purchases_2018_2 AS feb 
            GROUP BY feb.name
        ) as FebResult
        ON JanResult.Name = FebResult.Name;
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76dc02e/2).

Comment: this will not actually give you the result you required if one of the names is not present in the other table. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/998a3c/2